# AWS S3+Cloudfront access denied beginner question

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am having a small problem with my first time using cloudfront + s3. I just want to access my image via cloudfront. On S3, I have blocked all public access. Cloudfront origin is set to the S3 bucket.

The problem is when I am now trying to access my image via the cloudfront domain name.

XXX.cloudfront.net/folder/image.jpg

I get the error

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
```

However, if I set the public access on the s3 bucket

```
Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket or access point policies
S3 will ignore public and cross-account access for buckets or access points with policies that grant public access to buckets and objects.
```

Then i can view the image from the cloudfront link. is it possible to view the cloudfront image without having public access on?

Answer (score 2):

When you make your S3 objects private, they become inaccessible to the public—but CloudFront is no longer able to access them either. That is why you receive a 403 error. In order for this to work, you need to give CloudFront permission to access those private objects. You can do this by creating an **Origin Access Identity**, then setting the appropriate permissions on the S3 bucket so CloudFront is able to read the private objects.

Here are step-by-step instructions on how to do set this up in the CloudFront console:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#private-content-creating-oai-console